# Visual Studio 2012 Database Project - Construction of frame content failed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project

This might not be the right forum for an issue I'm having, however, I'm dead in the water until I can solve it.

My VS 2012 solution has a Database project: Database.sqlproj.

Today I hit a colliding package problem that led me to reinstall and repair Sql Server Data Tools to eliminate warnings. The activity log revealed that the installation apps had been creating incorrect names in the registry. Ten+ names in the registry had paths in which a backward slash had been left out between "Program Files(86)\Visual Studio 11.0" and "Common7". The path shown in the errors in the activity log looked like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0Common7
```

I searched for and corrected those errors in the registry, opened VS 2012 and my project without errors, or so I thought. **I discovered that I could no longer 'Publish' the database project**. Looking into the SQL Server Object Explorer and the activity log I now see this:

```
Construction of frame content failed. Frame identifier: 
ST:0:0:{fbcae063-e2c0-4ab1-a516-996ea3dafb72} Frame caption: SQL Server Object 
Explorer Exception details: System.ArgumentException: The parameter is 
incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) at 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 
errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) at 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode) at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 
id, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool) at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 
id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool) at 
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolWindowFactory.Create    ToolWindow(Guid& 
toolWindowType, UInt32 id) at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

Thanks for any help with this,

Arnold

Installation Information

Windows 7 Professional

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709

Installed Version: Professional

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012   04938-004-0033001-02913
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012

Visual Basic 2012   04938-004-0033001-02913
Microsoft Visual Basic 2012

Visual C# 2012   04938-004-0033001-02913
Microsoft Visual C# 2012

Visual C++ 2012   04938-004-0033001-02913
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012

Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint Developer Tools   04938-004-0033001-02913
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint Developer Tools

NuGet Package Manager   2.2.40116.9051
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.21208.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Telerik OpenAccess ORM   2012.3.1404.1
Telerik OpenAccess ORM Copyright © 1996–2012 Telerik AD
OpenAccess is the ultimate data access layer solution for Microsoft .NET database applications.
www.telerik.com/orm

Web Developer Tools   1.1.31017.0

Windows Azure Tools   October 2012
Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 - October 2012 v1.8.51019.1603

Answer (score 1):

OK. I uninstalled VS 2012 and then reinstalled with the latest version. That took care of all of the issues.